# Windows 10 IoT App not starting by default

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

My application is not starting by default, even though I configured it and it shows in the startup list.

I added my App through the command line command `iotstartup add headed SmartHomeController_m8d17z30eray2!App` which placed the app in the startup list:

```
[192.168.178.21]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> iotstartup startup
Headed   : SmartHomeController_m8d17z30eray2!App
```

The app seems to start but stack on the screen with the colored bars but never fully opens. My App's process is listed as running. What am I doing wrong?

Btw: I can successfully deploy, run and debug my app from Visual Studio. And I also tried the startup with a release version of the App already.

I am trying this on two separate Raspberry Pi2.

EDIT:
Here is the content of the WER Report that shows the Activation Failure of my app upon startup. I even tested it with the HelloWorld sample from Github, but no luck either.

WER-Report:

```
Version=1
EventType=WindowsPhone8ExecManService
EventTime=130796035482184453
ReportType=1
Consent=1
UploadTime=130796035502965782
ReportIdentifier=5e94ed6f-1a40-11e5-9a6c-b827ebbfa778
Response.BucketId=dbea6798d9ffe78cb5aebf0e09d609d0
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=111672501508
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=App
Sig[0].Value=C:\USERS\DefaultAccount\APPDATA\Local\DevelopmentFiles\HelloWorldIOTVS.Release_ARM.Sebastian\HelloWorldIOT.exe
Sig[1].Name=AppVer
Sig[1].Value=99999,
Sig[2].Name=AppID
Sig[2].Value={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Sig[3].Name=AppName
Sig[3].Value=unknown
Sig[4].Name=Reason
Sig[4].Value=EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT
Sig[5].Name=Description
Sig[5].Value=Activation Failure
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.10075.2.0.0.256.123
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=WindowsPhone8ExecManService
ConsentKey=WindowsPhone8ExecManService
AppName=Shell Infrastructure Host
AppPath=C:\Windows\system32\SIHOST.EXE
ApplicationIdentity=00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

The value EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT likely indicates that you have blocked the UI thread with a long running piece of code or a wait of some description.

Mark Radbourne [MSFT]